# PHONEGAP - Android, how do I get rid of the Quick Settings menu bar?

Tags: android, cordova, menu, settings

I try to find a way to disable the quick settings menu bar on Android devices (it appears at least on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S).  I mean the one on top of the screen when I swipe down. When I swipe the first time there is only a black small bar with some icons. When i swipe the second time, the whole menu opens and it covers the whole screen. I put already Fullscreen true in my config.xml. It still appears.
I searched forever but didn't find anything. Hope somebody can help me...

Thank you!

Comment: share the code you've tried so we can help you.

Comment: The only thing I'm using is <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true"/>. The rest is just a normal app, the content doesn't matter here.

Comment: All native full screen apps work this way, I do not believe there is a way to disable

Comment: hmm that's not good. I need the app to run more or less in kiosk mode. The case is covered by a metal case so the user is not able to press any buttons. But he is able to touch the display and so he can open that menu and change settings...etc.

Comment: I want to achieve the same. Does anyone found any solution for this?